# Linked Open Data Statistics

Tags: linked-data, uses-of-open-data

Where i can find a good document about Statistics of Linked open data cloud (organizations, number of triples and number of links) year by year?
In the official web site (lod cloud) there's only Statistics of 2011 and 2014. Where is the information about the other years?

Comment: Could you add more details: what country specifically? What is LOD? What type of data would you like to find?

Comment: @nelruk :  LOD == linked open data.

Answer (score 3):

[LOD Cloud](http://lod-cloud.net/) has some data/statistics from its beginnings, leading up to 2014, in a variety of formats: 
[LOD Cloud History](http://lod-cloud.net/#history)
Related information:
LOD Cloud explains how they mined the data for their sets, in particular the 2011 and 2014 datasets on their index page.
[LOD Cloud's datahub.io Account - All of the LOD Cloud Data is Stored Here](https://datahub.io/organization/lodcloud)